# Expression result unused in String Method

Tags: string, whitespace

I created this method to remove only the white space from the end of a string and not the beginning, while it returns the string perfectly and does what I need, the xcode interface tells me "Expression result unused" in the "for (lengthofthestring ; lengthofthestring > 0; lengthofthestring--)" line, CAN ANYONE TELL MY WHY, BEFORE I TEAR ALL MY HAIR OUT!!! thanks.
But it runs fine, (I don't want any hassles from the store)

Heres the code...

```
-(NSString *)removeEndSpaceFrom:(NSString *)strtoremove{
    NSUInteger location = 0;
    NSUInteger lengthofthestring = [strtoremove length];
    unichar charBuffer[lengthofthestring];
    [strtoremove getCharacters:charBuffer];
    ////////////// right here on the next line is where i'm getting the Expression result unused !!!
    for (lengthofthestring ; lengthofthestring > 0; lengthofthestring--) {
        if (![[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet] characterIsMember:charBuffer[lengthofthestring - 1]]){
            break;
        }
    }
    return  [strtoremove substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(location, lengthofthestring - location)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I fixed it this way, but I still don't know the answer to the above.

```
 -(NSString *)removeEndSpaceFrom:(NSString *)strtoremove{
    NSUInteger location = 0;
    unichar charBuffer[[strtoremove length]];
    [strtoremove getCharacters:charBuffer];
    int i = 0;
    for ( i = [strtoremove length]; i >0; i--){
        if (![[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet] characterIsMember:charBuffer[i - 1]]){
            break;
    }
    }
    return  [strtoremove substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(location, i  - location)];
}
```